# Python 2.7 Datetime Object Offset Unaware Even With Dateutil Parser

Tags: python, date, datetime

```
18 tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
19 TZOFFSETS = {'CST' : -21600}
20 POSTS_SINCE_HOUR = 1 
21 now_date = datetime.datetime.now(tz)
22 time_stamp = now_date - datetime.timedelta(hours=POSTS_SINCE_HOUR)
23 
24 thread_batch = []
25 for thread in threads:
26     last_post_time =  parse(
27             thread["LatestPostDate"],
28             tzinfos=TZOFFSETS)
29             
30     if last_post_time > time_stamp:
31         thread_batch.append(thread)


one@chat-dash ~/.willie $ python req.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "req.py", line 30, in <module>
    if last_post_time > time_stamp:
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

I don't understand why it is complaining about this. I used `datutil.parser` `parse` to make `last_post_time` offset-aware.

Comment: Have you printed out both datetimes to make sure the problem is what you think it is?

Comment: yes, the parser() isn't setting the timezone

Comment: What does the string going into `parse` look like?

Comment: before: 2014-02-03T14:49:33.663 and after: 2014-02-03 14:49:33.663000

Answer (score 1):

The `tzinfos` parameter to `parse` does not specify which timezone to use, it merely allows you to add new custom time zones to the ones that `dateutil` recognizes. To get a timezone in the resulting datetime, the string passed to `parse` must include a timezone string.

If your string doesn't include a time zone, you need to add the timezone yourself after the datetime is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I ended up disregarding the parse(), used datetime strptime, and then used localize() to add a timezone.